# How much do gas prices impact in other product prices?

Tags: inflation, transportation

In my country, they are considering stop funding gas prices so prices would raises from 0,30 U$S to 1 or 2 dollars per liter. Some people argues this would impact heavily in inflation, which is already rampant in this country, other people argues gas prices only impacts 2 to 4% in the products final prices. I found a lot of other articles stating "gas prices impact product prices" but not how much or how this impact can be calculated.

Is the impact of gas prices only 2% to 4%, or do they impact much more in the prices of products? I don't see how anyone could give a direct figure instead of a formula, considering that if a product has an x size and y price, and another product has the same size but a much higher price, the impact in the first should be much larger in % of the cost than in the second, shouldnt be?

How much do gas prices impact in other product prices, is there a formula or something to calculate it?